# Passar parâmetros de forma genérica através de um array

Tags: javascript

Tendo uma quantidade de argumentos variável e uma função genérica.
Quero fazer algo como:

```js
f(g,vetorArgs){
   return ()=>{
        //...codigo arbitrario
        g(vetorArgs[0],vetorArgs[1],vetorArgs[2],...,vetorArgs[n])
       //...mais codigo arbitrario
   }
}
```

Em suma o problema é que preciso chamar uma função `g` dentro de uma função `f` porem a função `g` é genérica e pode ter uma quantidade indefinida de argumentos desde 1 até n

A minha duvida é como transformar todos os elementos de `vetorArgs` em argumentos para a  função `g`.

A única coisa que consegui pensar foi concatenar os argumentos e usar `eval`.

```js
f(g,vetorArgs){
    strAux = ''
        vetorArgs.forEach(arg => {
            strAux = strAux + ',' + arg
        })
        strArgs = strAux.substring(1)
        strExec = 'g('+strArgs+')'
        eval(strExec)

    return ()=>{
        //...codigo arbitrario
        eval(strExec)
       //...mais codigo arbitrario
   }

}
```

---

### **[Resolvido]**

Com a ajuda do *@Luiz Felipe* consegui chegar no condigo que queria
Resultado:

```js
f(g,vetorArgs){
    return ()=>{
        //...codigo arbitrario
        g(...vetorArgs);  /* ou g.apply(null,vetorArgs)*/
       //...mais codigo arbitrario
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumindo que `vetorArgs` seja um array, você pode utilizar o [operador de espalhamento](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) para "espalhar" os argumentos para uma função, que aceitará um número variado de argumentos — recurso esse chamado de [parâmetros *rest*](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters). Assim:

```js
function myFunction(...args) {
  for (let i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
    console.log(args[i]); 
  }
}

const vectorArgs = [1, 2, 3, 4];

myFunction(...vectorArgs);
```

Esses dois recursos foram introduzidos com a especificação do ECMAScript 2015 (vulgo ES6). Desse modo, se você precisar fazer isso em ambientes que possam não suportar essas funcionalidades, você pode utilizar o método [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Apply), que recebe um *array* em seu segundo argumento e "espalha" seus elementos como argumentos para a função.

E de dentro dela, você pode utilizar o objeto (*array like*) [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) para acessá-los. Assim:

```js
function myFunction() {
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    console.log(arguments[i]);
  }
}

var vectorArgs = [1, 2, 3, 4];

// O primeiro argumento é o valor da variável "this" dentro da função a ser invocada.
// Neste caso pode ser `undefined`.
myFunction.apply(undefined, vectorArgs);
```

Mas note que no primeiro exemplo, `args` é de fato um *array*, que foi construindo usando a notação de parâmetros *rest*. No segundo exemplo, como disse acima, `arguments` não é um *array*, apesar de ter uma "assinatura" parecida. Desse modo, diz-se que `arguments` é um objeto *array-like*.

Então, se você receber uma função como argumento, pode utilizar qualquer um dos dois modos acima:

```js
// Utilizando o operador de espalhamento:
function withRest(fn, vector) {
  fn(...vector);
}

// Utilizando o método `apply`, presente no protótipo das funções.
function withArguments(fn, vector) {
  fn.apply(undefined, vector);
}

function g(a, b, c) {
  console.log(a + b + c);
}

withRest(g, [1, 2, 3]); // 6
withArguments(g, [1, 2, 3]); // 6
```

Mas eu realmente não vejo porquê de se fazer algo assim. Me parece que você só está re-implementando o `apply` ou complicando algo que não precisa.

Qual a diferença entre:

```
// Sua implementação:
f(g, [1, 2, 3]);
```

E:

```
g(...[1, 2, 3]);
```

Ou:

```
g.apply(undefined, [1, 2, 3]);
```

Comment: No meu caso ja existe uma função definida `f(a,b,c)` e outra `g(a,b)` e quero poder chamar dentro de uma função encapsuladora 
`encapsuladora (functionGenerica,vetorArrays){functionGenerica(vetorArrays[0],...,vetorArrays[n])}`


Pelo o que entendi da sua explicação eu teria que reescrever as funções `f(...vetArgs)` e a `g(...vetArgs)`

Comment: @le314u, editei a resposta.

Comment: Ok, porfavor olhe se ficou mais compreensível.

Comment: No caso que vc citou no final, a minha primeira implementação estava tentando replicar ( mesmo não querendo isso), depois da sua explicação consegui chegar no meu objetivo de fato que era encapsular uma função que executa outra fazendo uso do parâmetro rest